# UISearchController UISearchBar is not vissible in IOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have `UISearchController` in my app and this is the code I'm using to create it:

```
-(void)setSearchBar {
    self.resultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.resultsController.tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.self forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SearchTitleCell"];
    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsController];
    [self.searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:self];
    [self.searchController setDelegate:self];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.1")) {
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    }

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;

    self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

I noticed that in IOS 13 it's working fine, but in IOS 12 I can't see the `searchbar` as shown in the photos:

IOS 13:
[image]

IOS 12:
[image]

Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 12 the search bar is shown below the results controller.
To fix that you have to set `self.definesPresentationContext = true` for the main controller in your code.
You can also do this on a storyboard.